# How to sort a table in excel with macros - search and count duplicates

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I have a problem - at my work I have a sheet with tables in this format:

```
   Column1       Column2
   AA-AA-A1      AA-01-B1
   AA-AA-A1      AA-02-B2
   AA-AB-B5      AA-06-B7
```

What I want to do is - show only duplicates in first column, count how many times it duplicates and copy those duplicates next to for example to Column 4 or 5 in format: AA-AA-A1 2. 
I was doing before a conditional formating, but it takes too much time to check 10,000 rows for duplicates because of color.
Thanks for your answers.

Comment: If speed is an issue, use variant arrays and scripting dictionaries.

Comment: You could use countif, =IF(COUNTIF($A$1:$A$10000,A1)>1,$A1 & " duplicated " & COUNTIF($A$1:$A$10000,$A1) & " times.","No Dupes")

Comment: To show the duplicates you can use an array formula, do you wish to show dupes also, or just how many?

Comment: Array formula =IFERROR(SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$10000=$A1,ROW($A$1:$A$10000)),1),"") will show the rows where the dupes are, the last 1, changing to 2,3,4,5,6 etc, will show them in ascending order.

Comment: Dopes + numbers for example AA-01-A1:2

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Sub test()
    lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("A2", "A" & lastrow).Copy Range("C2")
    Range("C2:C4").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
    lastrowunique = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To lastrowunique
        Cells(i, 4) = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A:A"), Cells(i, 3))
    Next i
End Sub
```